# Labels for Pie Graph, Python

Tags: python, pie-chart

Is there a way I don't have to manually write out the labels for a pie chart. My labels are the numeric values 0-23, and I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to go about this. I'm also wondering if I can basically do the same for colors, and explode-- where I don't have to give a total of 24 values for labels, colors, or explode.

```
labels = 
colors = 
x= acc_time
explode = 
plt.pie(x, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, radius=10.0, frame=True, startangle=190)
plt.title('Collisions per Hour')
plt.axis('equal')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
pie = plt.pie(x, labels=labels, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=190,radius=1.8)
plt.legend(pie[0],labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="lower left", fontsize=12, 
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

Comment: numpy.arange() can generate the numbered labels for you

Comment: `labels=range(24)`